# Show/hide fieldset based on radio button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button, show-hide

I'm trying to have the email/phone number section of a contact form hidden or visible depending on whether the user picks the phone or email radio button, but I cannot figure out why it is not working for me.
I've searched through stack overflow & w3Schools, and I'm pretty certain I'm using the correct syntax but it will still not show/hide depending on the radio buttons.
Any help would be hugely appreciated!

HTML

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="result.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Client's contact details -->
                    <legend>Contact Details</legend>
                        <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact" id="fullname" required>

                        <label>Preferred contact method:</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="rdoPhone" id="rdoPhone" checked="checked" onclick="cPhone()" >Phone
                        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="rdoEmail" id="rdoEmail" onclick="cEmail()" >Email

                        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact" id="phonenumber">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact" id="email">
                </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#email {
display:none;
}       
#phonenumber {
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
function cPhone() {
if (document.getElementById("rdoPhone").checked)
{ document.getElementById("phonenumber").style.display = "block"; }
}

function cEmail(){
if (document.getElementById("rdoEmail").checked)
{ document.getElementById("email").style.display = "block"; }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, please don't consider `w3Schools` as a valid source.

Comment: What site would you recommend as a better source for javascript/html?

Comment: [M](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Reference)[D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference)[N](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) for reference, [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/) for detailed stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Since phone number is checked by default, you should not hide it initially.
- You don't have to check for the `checked` property on click of a radio in a radio button group, because a click will always select it.

You can use a common function for this purpose as follows -

- apply the class `hide` given below initially for the email.
- call the function `showHide(this)` given below `onClick` of both radios

css

```
.hide {
 display:none;
}
```

js

```
function showHide(elm) {
 var phone = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
 var email = document.getElementById("email")
 if(elm.id == 'rdoPhone'){
    phone.classList.remove('hide');
    email.classList.add('hide');
 }
 else
 {
    phone.classList.add('hide');
    email.classList.remove('hide');
 }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aELdJ/13/)

Comment: Thank you, that works brilliantly. That's a great idea also to add/remove the one class with a CSS style, it makes it more flexible, and I can also use it further down the form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to apply it directly in javascript:

$('#id-element').css('display', 'block');

$('#id-element').css('display', 'none');

Comment: this is not *directly* in javascript this is jquery.